# JavaScript / jQuery input[type=text] pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, date, input

Ok well, i have an input in a form, which is a date input. I want it to accept characters based on a pattern like "XX/XX/XXXX". Currently it accepts only numbers and "/". But i don't want users to enter dates like "X/XXXX/XX" or some other kind, and i don't want to be able to write it wrong like "//XX/XXX/XXX". I don't know how to use js on this one, or jQuery so the user inputs the date based on the pattern and not in some other way.

Comment: For masking input, remember that you want to be able to accept a partially valid input as well. You shouldn't block `XX/X/XXXX`, because then you'd prevent the user from correcting a typo - this is very frustrating. What you want to do is reject obviously invalid input (e.g. alphabetic characters in your case) by masking, then check if the final input is invalid when the input field loses focus or when the form is being submitted. (Also frustrating: preventing the user from tabbing out of an invalid field.)

Comment: Not widely supported yet, but HTML5 has `<input type="date">` with an appropriate UI.

Answer (score 3):

Cheap and easy approach might be just to implement the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats) control so that you can control the input format through that.

It's basically side-stepping the problem but might take the actual problem out of the equation for you.

Answer (score 1):

take a look for :
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex `^(3[0-1]|[0-2]?[0-9])\/(0?[0-9]|1[0-2])\/(2[0-9]+)$`:

```
var date = "20/12/2012";

console.log(isDateOK(date));

function isDateOK(date) {
    return date.match(/^(3[0-1]|[0-2]?[0-9])\/(0?[0-9]|1[0-2])\/([1-2][0-9]{3})$/);
}
```

It will return false if it doesn't match. This example uses DD/MM/YYYY. if you want MM/DD/YYYY, use the following regex instead: `^(0?[0-9]|1[0-2])\/(3[0-1]|[0-2]?[0-9])\/[1-2][0-9]{3$`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UBFeN/2/

Comment: Yes it does, but it's a simple was of adding input security, so you can be sure what they typed was correct. Sure you'd hit a year 3000 bug, but if someone is still using this JS by then, I'm sure they'd figure it out. Of course the `2[0-9]{3}` should be exchanged with `[0-9]{4}` if you want to use it past year 3K.

Comment: lol I was more concerned with dates before 2000 than after 3000 tbh. Oh and there is no input security when validating with js. I much prefer using a library or the Date classes/types constructors to validate both client and server side.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, silly silly me. You're completely correct! Changed the post :D